# Autofac: creating nested scopes per instance on-the-fly

Tags: c#, autofac, ioc-container

I would like to implement an application-wide container and a (nested) one for each project created by the user. I looked into `Owned<T>`, but then - as far as I could figure it out - my internal collection of projects would have to be `<Owned<Project>>` which I do not want and also I failed to inject a project dependency into objects used within the project scope ("circular component dependency"). I considered using a new ContainerBuilder within the project factory, but then the "nested" aspect is missing.

A few exapmles of classes (with the dependencies) I would like to have:

- In a global scope: `ProjectManager(IProjectFactory)`
- In each project's scope: `Project(IDocumentFactory documentFactory)`, `Document(IProject project, IProjectSettings settings)`.

So for the project's scope I would register `IDocumentFactory`, `IProjectSettings` (and the project itself?).

When a project is closed/disposed all created dependencies should, of course, also be disposed.

If possible, the concrete classes (except for the ProjectFactory) should be Autofac-agnostic.

FYI: The application is a desktop application using C# and Autofac 4.8.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Thanks for your comments, the discussion helped me find my own opinion. Currently I'm settling for something like this in my `ProjectFactory`:

```
    public Project Create()
    {
        var scope = _globalScope.BeginLifetimeScope(MyIocHelper.RegisterProjectDependencies);

        var p = scope.Resolve<Project>();

        _projectScopes.Add(p, scope);
        p.Disposing += project_Disposing;

        return p;
    }
```

Things to note:

- As far as I can tell, using a tag for the lifetime scope is not necessary.
- `Project` raises a `Disposing` event when its `Dispose` method is called the first time.
- The factory keeps a `Dictionary<Project, ILifetimeScope>` and cleans it up when the project is disposed.

Comment: Actually, it just occurred to me that you probably want to have some collection of documents in the project and use it somewhere, for example, on UI to show doc names to the user. In this case I would suggest against using autofac for managing documents. Container does not have such a function as providing a list of documents currently available in the scope, so you'll have to keep track of them in the project. But now you are introducing conflict of lifecycle management - now Project AND container are concerned about document objects lifetime, and who should be responsible for disposing them?

Comment: So, please clarify the very high level functions of this system so that we could understand lifecycles of the entities involved. Better not to provide your thoughts on the implementation because it will not be useful while not having design settled first.

Comment: I get your notion about conflicting dispose chains and am considering using autofac for the factories only - also because of the performance hit I'm expecting from resolving the dependencies for every instance (of documents and nested items).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish what you are looking for with a combination of named lifetime scopes and instance-per-lifetime-scope registrations.

Documentation here: http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/working-with-scopes.html#tagging-a-lifetime-scope

You need to:

1. register your ProjectManager as SingleInstance
2. register Project as this:

   ```
        builder.Register<Project>()
           .As<IProject>()
           .InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("project");
   ```

   This will guarantee that a Project can be resolved (e.g. by a Document) once per each scope tagged as "project".
3. Implement an OpenProject (or something along) method in ProjectManager. This method should instantiate a LifetimeScope tagged as "project", register in it the `IDocumentFactory`, `IProjectSettings`, so they are resolved only once for each project scope, and attach the scope itself onto the Project instance. *This is crucial*: you need the scope to be disposed when you dispose the project.

   ```
   public class ProjectManager : IProjectFactory
   {
       private readonly ILifetimeScope _scope;

       public ProjectManager(ILifetimeScope scope)
       {
           // this is going to be the global scope.
           _scope = scope;
       }


       public Project OpenProject(IDocumentFactory docFactory, IProjectSettings settings)
       {
           var projectScope = _scope.BeginLifetimeScope("project");
           projectScope.RegisterInstance(docFactory).AsImplementedInterfaces();
           projectScope.RegisterInstance(settings).AsImplementedInterfaces();

           return projectScope.Resolve<Project>();
       }
   }

   public class ProjectScope : IDisposable
   {
       private readonly ILifetimeScope _scope;

       public ProjectManager(ILifetimeScope scope)
       {
           // this is going to be the project scope.
           _scope = scope;
       }

       public void Dispose() {
           if (_scope != null) {
               _scope.Dispose();
               _scope = null;
           }
       }
   }

   public class Project : IDisposable
   {
       private readonly ProjectScope _scope; 

       public Project(ProjectScope scope /*, ...*/)
       {
           _scope = scope;
       }

       public void Dispose() {
           // pay attention that this method will be called 2 times, once by you
           // and another time by the underlying LifetimeScope. So this code should
           // handle that gracefully (so the _scope == null).
           if (_scope != null) {
               _scope.Dispose();
               _scope = null;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Given all this, you keep every `using Autofac` out of every class, with the 2 exceptions of the global manager and the ProjectScope. You can change some bits on how the scope is handled, if you accept a single `using Autofac` in the `Project` class itself: you can get directly the `ILifetimeScope` and dispose of it directly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `ProjectScope` doesn't seem to be correct. It's provided with the _external_ lifetime scope and then this scope gets disposed of explicitly _by the ProjectScope object_ - which is **not** what it should be doing. Scope is not **owned** by the `ProjectScope` object, thus it cannot know when is the correct time to kill the scope. Most likely this will break autofac's scope management and will lead to hard-to-understand errors in the application. But in general I'd say that your answer points to the right direction.

Comment: The idea is that disposal of Project cascades to the LifetimeScope containing it. Ence, I dispose the Autofac's LifetimeScope from ProjectScope. I know it's kind of opposite of what someone would usually do, but I don't think it's wrong. Simply put, disposing of Project would automagically Dispose all the other objects contained in the enclosing "project" scope. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. You absolutely should not dispose lifetime scope that you did not start. In any case. Besides, disposing of Project should mean that it gets done through the killing the scope as well - which will take care of killing everything under it without requiring you to do anything.

Comment: if a. chiesa's suggestion is "sub-optimal", what would be a better solution? are my requirements far fetched or heading in the wrong direction?

Comment: Well, even if I consider (as a personal opinion) the position of Alexander a little too dogmatic, the points he makes are right. You should ensure that the objects living in the scope of the Project are NOT externally referenced (or you will have references to disposed objects when the Project scope disposes). As an alternative, you could implement the logic of scope instantiation and management directly onto the Project class. In this case, you would give the responsibility of managing the disposal of the LifetimeScope to the same class instantiating it, keeping the code "tighter".

Comment: I'm not about being dogmatic. :) It's more of a common sense. If someone gave you some object then you should ONLY dispose it if you are explicitly directed so. It is especially right with autofac. One more time - you should dispose only those scopes that you created manually using BeginLifetimeScope(), otherwise you'll break something in autofac. And if you create project by resolving it from the DI container then you should not dispose project yourself as well. Scope is called "lifetime" for a good reason. ;) You should dispose scope instead and that will kill everything else.

Comment: I’m with you about every word. I was suggesting a solution in which the creation of the scope is always performed by a class and the disposal is always performed by another. I agree it could be problematic in some circumstances, but in some other it _could_ be acceptable, if other conditions prevent the bad consequences you where mentioning. Great points, still.

Comment: @A.Chiesa: Thanks for the detailed answer! This may be a bit of autofac abuse, but sometimes it's best to know when not to follow best practices. And in this case I also think it may be acceptable. If I find any drawbacks, I'll update this post.